# Generating Functions and Polynomials in Tiling problems

Tags: combinatorics, convergence-divergence, generating-functions

I recently met these two tiling problems.

> 1. For a set $S$ and an integer $a$, let $S+a=\{s+a | s\in S\}$. Suppose there exists a set $X$ integers $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ such that $X+a_1, \cdots, X+a_n$ partition $\mathbb{Z}$. Show that there exists an integer $N$ such that $X=X+N$

> 2. Let $S$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb{Z}^2$. Define the *tile* $T_v = \{v+s | s\in S\}$ where $v\in \mathbb{Z}^2$. Suppose $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is partitioned into tiles of the form $T_v$. Prove that there exists $w\in \mathbb{Z}^2$ such that if $T_v$ is used in the partition, then so is $T_{v+w}$.

I can easily rephrase problem 1 to be a one-dimensional version of problem 2 if I define $T_v=\{v+a_1,\cdots,v+a_n\}$ and both problems asks us to show that the tiling follows some periodic pattern. I know both problems are solvable with pure combinatorial methods, but I am wondering if I can use generating functions to deal with them. So I thought of the following modification for 1:

> Let $f(x)$ be a formal series and $P(x)$ be a polynomial. Both have coefficients in $\{0,1\}$. If $f(x)P(x)=1+x+\cdots+x^t+\cdots =\frac{1}{1-x}$, then show that $f(x)=\frac{Q(x)}{1-x^N}$ for some polynomial $Q$.

This is the same as problem 1, but with $\mathbb{Z}$ replaced by $\mathbb{N}$.

To prove this, one can note that $P(x)\ne 0$ for all $|x|<1$, so by Vieta's formula, all roots of $P$ lie on the unit circle. By Kronecker, all roots are positive integers, i.e. $P(x)|(x^m-1)^k$ for some integers $m,k$. If $k=1$ we are done, but if $k>1$ (ie $P$ has a double root) things are annoying. I must use the fact that $f,P$ only have $0,1$ as coefficients in some nice way. Any advice will be appreciated.

Also, back to $\mathbb{Z}$, then this is saying if $f(x)$ is a series (allowing $x^t$ for $t<0$) then $f(x)P(x) = \sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} x^n$. Note the right hand thing doesn't converge anywhere in $\mathbb{C}$. Is it possible to deal with this using generating functions?

Comment: Some ideas that might be helpful: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2805660p24734461 (may or may not imply Z and N are equivalent), https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2805662p24734467 (see CANBANKAN's post)